# Rewrite conditions in Lighttpd for Slim Framework and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lighttpd, slim

I need to migrate an Apache php based web site to a lighttpd but I get some problems to change it.

My dir extructure is:

```
-rootdir
--index.php¹
--login.php²
--views²
--server
---service³
---auth³
```

¹ In the rootdir the rewrite rule in Apache was:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

² login.php file and views folder need be avoided by rewrite
³ server/auth and server/service Directories have your own rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Trying build a rule, and almost all is right, but /server/service not

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
                "^/login.php\/?([^.]+)$/" => "/login.php/$1", #ok
                "^/(views|assets|css|images|application)/(.*)" => "$0", #ok
                "/server/service/.*\?(.*)$" => "/server/service/index.php?$1", #return rewrite response of rootdir/index.php
                "/server/auth/.*\?(.*)$" => "/server/auth/index.php?$1", #ok
                "/.*\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html)$" => "$0", #ok
                "/.*\?(.*)$" => "/index.php?$1",
               "" => "/index.php"
         )
```

example of usages:

www.example.com/home/id/2 <-- use /rootdir/index.php
www.example.com/server/auth/check/sessionid2235232132 <-- use /server/auth/index.php
www.example.com/server/server/db/clients/getall <-- use /server/service/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way out to migrate some specific cases like that.

After some try and tests I achieved this rules to this case.

```
 url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
                "^/login.php\/?([^.]+)$/" => "/login.php/$1",
                "^/(views|assets|css|images|application)/(.*)" => "$0",
                "/server/auth/.*\?(.*)$" => "/server/auth/index.php?$1",
                "/server/service/.*\?(.*)$" => "/server/service/index.php?$1",
                "/.*\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html)$" => "$0", #ok
                ".*\?(.*)$" => "/index.php?$1",
                "" => "/index.php"
    )
```

To avoid rewrite conditions on a specific file:

```
 "^/login.php\/?([^.]+)$/" => "/login.php/$1",
```

To avoid rewrite condition on a specific folder(s):

```
 "^/login.php\/?([^.]+)$/" => "/login.php/$1",
```

To rewrite querystring for a especific files in a specific folder

```
"/server/auth/.*\?(.*)$" => "/server/auth/index.php?$1",
"/server/service/.*\?(.*)$" => "/server/service/index.php?$1",
```

To avoid rewrite at some files(It make no sense but it should be skiped when we use rewrite-if-not-file)

```
"/.*\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html)$" => "$0",
```

When we use javascrip front-end like Angularjs with friendly url its very important to create this 2 rules of rewriting.

```
".*\?(.*)$" => "/index.php?$1",
"" => "/index.php"
```

Im my scenario I have 2 server backends (auth and service) using slimframework, and i have a frontend in AngularJS 
This rules allow me rewrite urls at backend and frontend with no problems.